# How to schedule a search to run every 5 minutes in Splunk?

Tags: search, cron, schedule, splunk

I am searching for some data on splunk for a 5 minute time range. I want this query to run after every 5 minutes in splunk on it's own. How can this be done? I tried finding it on splunk but all I can see is how to schedule alerts and reports. And after the query is activated, how can we access the produced results generated by  the query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically you can have a scheduled search, but it only makes sense to talk about a report or an alert. Your scheduled approach is actually the best-practice (as there is also the possibility for a real-time search of the last 5 minutes).

- If you just want a report, you tell Splunk to email it to you either as an HTML table or as a PDF document.
- If you only want to be alerted if some condition matches (i.e. more than X results) then you want to set up an alert.
- Scheduled searches are available, but they are a bit tricky to access (imho)

In the alerts/reports schedule options you have to set the following:

- Earliest: `-6m@m`
- Latest: `-1m@m`
- Cron expression: `*/5 * * * *`

Don't forget to set some trigger condition (for an alert) or a delivery method (for the report) ;)